# Installing Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-11.10

I was trying to in stall `Google Plugin` for `Eclipse 3.7(Indigo)` the other day, and whenever I click on NEXT button gives me the following error :-

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.5.2.v201202290255-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 2.5.2.v201202290255-rel-r37)
Missing requirement: com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android 2.5.2.v201202290255-rel-r37 requires 'bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 12.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.5.2.v201202290255-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 2.5.2.v201202290255-rel-r37)
To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android [2.5.2.v201202290255-rel-r37]
```

I have also tried adding this to [available software site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) but still same issue. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPE has an optional Android section that you can uncheck.  The Android section requires that you have the Android sdk installed first.  If you don't need the Android stuff then uncheck that in the install, otherwise install the sdk first.